# bash script executed by httpd does not read user environmental variables

Tags: bash, apache, amazon-ec2

We have a script that is executed by httpd as the default ec2-user. However when executed the script does not see any of the environmental variables for that user

the variable is set under user `ec2-user`

```
myUseVarHome=/home/ec2-user
```

myScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
myFolder="${myUseVarHome}/test/www"
USER=$(whoami)
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "hello $USER"
echo "myFolder=$myFolder"
```

executing script as `ec2-user` outputs

```
hello ec2-user
myFolder=/home/ec2-user/test/www
```

We then set httpd 2.4 conf

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
    User ec2-user
    Group ec2-user
</IfModule>
```

now call the script with

```
wget 127.0.0.1/myScript.sh
```

outputs

```
hello ec2-user
myFolder=/test/www
```

The output validates the httpd user is `ec2-user`, same as manually executing the script, however the env variable `${myUseVarHome}` is blank or does not exist.

Is this expected behaviour or do we need to call the env variable another way when executed as httpd user?

Comment: Yes, this is expected behavior. Environment variables are per process, not per user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` acts differently whether it is a **shell** or a normal **progamming language** (like `perl` or `python`).

By designed, those settings in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, etc. are for users to set things when `bash` plays **the roll of a shell** (login shell, interractive shell). Think about environment you have in a `xterm` (interractive shell) or in `ssh` sessions (login shell) or in consoles (login shell).

In other hand, `bash` is also a powerfull **progamming language** --think about many scripts for managing services in `systemd`-- which requires a different style of working. Example, when a developer write a system script or a `bash` program, he/she will not likely to source user defined `~/.bash_profile` automatically. It is a normal program, not a shell. A normal program (including `bash` programs) would naturally **inherrit** setting in a current working evironement (shell), but not **set** them.

If we write a program for `cron` in `bash` --it is just happenly it is written in `bash`; in fact, we can write it in `python` or `perl` or any other progamming language-- then, we can have an option to sources `bash`'s `~/.bash_profile` (read: setting of user's shell, which happenly to be the same language of your programming language):

```
[ -f /home/user/.bash_profile ] && . /home/user/.bash_profile
```

However, what if that particular user do not use `bash` as his/her shell? He/she may use `zsh`, 'ksh`,`fish`, etc. So, that's practice does not really work when writing program for public use.

So, you can source `~/.bash_profile` if you think it work. But, here, it is not about whether we are able to source a file, it is about how things should works in the system: **the design concept**. In short: **we should view `bash` as something having 2 rolls: shell and progamming language**. Then everything will be clear, easier to understand.

See: [How to change cron shell sh to bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash)